# Setting a timeout handler on a promise in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, jasmine, promise

I'm trying to set a timeout in my controller so that if a response isn't received in 250ms it should fail. I've set my unit test to have a timeout of 10000 so that this condition should be met,Can anyone point me in the right direction? ( EDIT I'm trying to achieve this without using the $http service which I know provides timeout functinality)

(EDIT - my other unit tests were failing because I wasn't calling timeout.flush on them, now I just need to get the timeout message kicking in when an undefined promise is returned by promiseService.getPromise(). I've removed the early code from the question) .

promiseService (promise is a test suite variable allowing me to use different behaviour for the promise in each test suite before apply, eg reject in one, success in another)

```
    mockPromiseService = jasmine.createSpyObj('promiseService', ['getPromise']);
    mockPromiseService.getPromise.andCallFake( function() {
        promise = $q.defer();
        return promise.promise;
    })
```

Controller function that's being tested -

```
$scope.qPromiseCall = function() {
    var timeoutdata = null;
    $timeout(function() {
        promise = promiseService.getPromise();
        promise.then(function (data) {
                timeoutdata = data;
                if (data == "promise success!") {
                    console.log("success");
                } else {
                    console.log("function failure");
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("promise failure")
            }

        )
    }, 250).then(function (data) {
        if(typeof timeoutdata === "undefined" ) {
            console.log("Timed out")
        }
    },function( error ){
        console.log("timed out!");
    });
}
```

Test (normally I resolve or reject the promise in here but by not setting it I'm simulating a timeout)

```
it('Timeout logs promise failure', function(){
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    scope.qPromiseCall();
    $timeout.flush(251);
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Timed out");
})
```

Comment: Can you show us `promiseService.getPromise()`?

Comment: It's not implemented yet I'm trying to get this designed first, should it be linked to the implementation of the promise service?

Comment: How can you tell it's not working if you haven't implemented it yet

Comment: It's a unit test so I'm injecting the promiseService.getPromise... as I type this I realise I don't have the inject code, adding now sry

Comment: I don't see the number '250' anywhere in your code there... how do you expect it to do something after 250 ms?

Comment: I cleaned up the code after several failed attempts, I was hoping for a shove in the right direction. hang on I'll post the last thing I tried

Comment: I've removed older code and cleaned up the question, please let me know if you need any more info

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, I would like to say that your controller implementation should be something like this:

```
$scope.qPromiseCall = function() {

    var timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
      canceler.resolve(); //aborts the request when timed out
      console.log("Timed out");
    }, 250); //we set a timeout for 250ms and store the promise in order to be cancelled later if the data does not arrive within 250ms

    var canceler = $q.defer();
    $http.get("data.js", {timeout: canceler.promise} ).success(function(data){
      console.log(data);

      $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise); //cancel the timer when we get a response within 250ms
    });
  }
```

Your tests:

```
it('Timeout occurs', function() {
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    $scope.qPromiseCall();
    $timeout.flush(251); //timeout occurs after 251ms
    //there is no http response to flush because we cancel the response in our code. Trying to  call $httpBackend.flush(); will throw an exception and fail the test
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Timed out");
  })

  it('Timeout does not occur', function() {
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    $scope.qPromiseCall();
    $timeout.flush(230); //set the timeout to occur after 230ms
    $httpBackend.flush(); //the response arrives before the timeout
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith("Timed out");
  })
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/CEoJy7B2X0uX1uEUk0Yq?p=preview)

Another example with `promiseService.getPromise`:

```
app.factory("promiseService", function($q,$timeout,$http) {
  return {
    getPromise: function() {
      var timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
        console.log("Timed out");

        defer.reject("Timed out"); //reject the service in case of timeout
      }, 250);

      var defer = $q.defer();//in a real implementation, we would call an async function and 
                             // resolve the promise after the async function finishes

      $timeout(function(data){//simulating an asynch function. In your app, it could be
                              // $http or something else (this external service should be injected
                              //so that we can mock it in unit testing)
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise); //cancel the timeout 

         defer.resolve(data);
      });

      return defer.promise;
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, promiseService) {

  $scope.qPromiseCall = function() {

    promiseService.getPromise().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data); 
    });//you could pass a second callback to handle error cases including timeout

  }
});
```

Your tests are similar to the above example:

```
it('Timeout occurs', function() {
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    spyOn($timeout, 'cancel');
    $scope.qPromiseCall();
    $timeout.flush(251); //set it to timeout
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Timed out");
  //expect($timeout.cancel).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  //I also use $timeout to simulate in the code so I cannot check it here because the $timeout is flushed
  //In real app, it is a different service
  })

it('Timeout does not occur', function() {
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    spyOn($timeout, 'cancel');
    $scope.qPromiseCall();
    $timeout.flush(230);//not timeout
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith("Timed out");
    expect($timeout.cancel).toHaveBeenCalled(); //also need to check whether cancel is called
  })
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8yXkN6TkDNW1Bg8G78e8?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks unfortunately I accidentally edited the part of my question which requires this to be for a promise not handled by $http service as I know that has a built-in timeout handler, would you be able to update for this scenario?

Comment: @LinuxN00b: did you look at my second example? Does it meet your requirement?

Comment: Thanks you I'm still having my morning coffee so I completely missed the second demo. In this example, in real life, how would you go about handling the timeout for the promiseService promise in a way that's clean and prevents the promise from returning later at an unexpected time and triggering an issue?

Comment: @LinuxN00b: check my updated answer to see it you're satisfied. In this example, I move all of the code to one function. This is just a demo of the idea. The keys are rejecting the promise if timeout occurs and cancelling timeout if the response arrives before the timeout.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you had to click to also award the bounty I was satisfied anyway. Edit - it's saying 3 hours until I can accept, will do so then, thank you very much

Comment: @LinuxN00b: I added an asynch simulation to the answer to make it clearer and one more check in the unit test to check whether `$timeout.cancel` was called or not.

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour of "failing a promise unless it is resolved with a specified timeframe" seems ideal for refactoring into a separate service/factory. This should make the code in both the new service/factory and controller clearer and more re-usable.

The controller, which I've assumed just sets the success/failure on the scope:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, failUnlessResolvedWithin, myPromiseService) {
  failUnlessResolvedWithin(function() {
    return myPromiseService.getPromise();
  }, 250).then(function(result) {
    $scope.result = result;
  }, function(error) {
    $scope.error = error;
  });
});
```

And the factory, `failUnlessResolvedWithin`, creates a new promise, which effectively "intercepts" a promise from a passed in function. It returns a new one that replicates its resolve/reject behaviour, except that it also rejects the promise if it hasn't been resolved within the timeout:

```
app.factory('failUnlessResolvedWithin', function($q, $timeout) {

  return function(func, time) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.reject('Not resolved within ' + time);
    }, time);

    $q.when(func()).then(function(results) {
      deferred.resolve(results);
    }, function(failure) {
      deferred.reject(failure);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };
});
```

The tests for these are a bit tricky (and long), but you can see them at http://plnkr.co/edit/3e4htwMI5fh595ggZY7h?p=preview . The main points of the tests are

- The tests for the controller mocks `failUnlessResolvedWithin` with a call to `$timeout`.

  ```
  $provide.value('failUnlessResolvedWithin', function(func, time) {
    return $timeout(func, time);
  });
  ```

  This is possible since 'failUnlessResolvedWithin' is (deliberately) syntactically equivalent to `$timeout`, and done since `$timeout` provides the `flush` function to test various cases.
- The tests for the service itself uses calls `$timeout.flush` to test behaviour of the various cases of the original promise being resolved/rejected before/after the timeout.

  ```
  beforeEach(function() {
    failUnlessResolvedWithin(func, 2)
    .catch(function(error) {
      failResult = error;
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function() {
    $timeout.flush(3);
    $rootScope.$digest();
  });

  it('the failure callback should be called with the error from the service', function() {
    expect(failResult).toBe('Not resolved within 2');
  });
  ```

You can see all this in action at http://plnkr.co/edit/3e4htwMI5fh595ggZY7h?p=preview

Comment: Thanks unfortunately I accidentally edited the part of my question which requires this to be for a promise not handled by $http service as I know that has a built-in timeout handler, would you be able to update for this scenario?

Comment: I don't think my answer requires anything relating to the `$http` service. The `getPromise` can be any function that returns a promise. Can you clarify why you think it does? Or if I'm misunderstanding, clarify your requirements in the question.

Comment: The answer feeds the timeout to the $http call which handles the timeout doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by feeding, but the only Angular services I'm using are `$q` and `$timeout`. Neither of them then call anything from `$http` (as far as I know).

Comment: @MichalCharemza +1 I added an answer that is  a derivative of your original answer.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation of @Michal Charemza 's failUnlessResolvedWithin with a real sample.
By passing deferred object to the func it reduces having to instantiate a promise in usage code "ByUserPosition". Helps me deal with firefox and geolocation.

```
.factory('failUnlessResolvedWithin', ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {

    return function(func, time) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
            deferred.reject('Not resolved within ' + time);
        }, time);

        func(deferred);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}])



            $scope.ByUserPosition = function () {
                var resolveBy = 1000 * 30;
                failUnlessResolvedWithin(function (deferred) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function (position) {
                        deferred.resolve({ latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude });
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    }, {
                        enableHighAccuracy : true,
                        timeout: resolveBy,
                        maximumAge: 0
                    });

                }, resolveBy).then(findByPosition, function (data) {
                    console.log('error', data);
                });
            };
```