# Angular $http config timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest, angular-promise, angular-http

As documented in the angular docs,

> **timeout – {number|Promise}** – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.

Right now I am setting timeout to promise, so I can manually cancel the request by `promise.resolve()`.

Right now, I also want to make it capable to config timeout value, instead of having the request timeout being 120 seconds.

How can I configure it without affecting the existing cancel request functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do somthing like this

```
$scope.qPromiseCall = function()
{
       var timeoutPromise = $timeout(function()
       {       
               //aborts the request when timed out
               canceler.resolve(); 
               console.log("Timed out");
        }, 250); 

//we set a timeout for 250ms and store the promise in order to be cancelled later if the data does not arrive within 250ms

     var canceler = $q.defer();
     $http.get("data.js", {timeout: canceler.promise} )
     .success(function(data)
     {
           console.log(data);
           $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
           //cancel the timer when we get a response within 250ms
    });

  }
```

For more details look at

[Setting a timeout handler on a promise in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994871/setting-a-timeout-handler-on-a-promise-in-angularjs/23038671#23038671)

First Answer by @Khanh TO