# AngularJS- $timeout to abort if promise isn't resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am using AngularJS and Typescript. In my controller constructor, I make a call to a function that gets data and returns a promise. The promise is stored in the variable `x`.

```
x.then((data) => {
   //displays data
}, (err) => {
   //sends error message
});
```

Right now if the promise never resolves, it displays nothing. I want to use `$timeout` so that if the resolution of `x` takes too long it will display another message. I don't know how I can do it for promises. Calling `this.$timeout(3000,true).then(() => {});` just delays the contents and I can delay a function. How can I abort if the promise doesn't resolve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS Timeout a Promise if failed to complete in time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461271/nodejs-timeout-a-promise-if-failed-to-complete-in-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a timeout handler on a promise in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994871/setting-a-timeout-handler-on-a-promise-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS v1.6 introduces the [$q.race method](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/docs/api/ng/service/$q#race) which can be used to abort a promise:

```
var timeoutPromise = $timeout(null, delay).then(() => {throw "Timeout Abort" });

var timedPromise = $q.race(xPromise, timeoutPromise);
```

In this example, `timedPromise` will either resolve (fulfilled or rejected) with the results of `xPromise` or be rejected with the reason "Timeout Abort" whichever comes first.