# Angular js reject load script after some delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

I am loading some scripts in my project using angular loadscript.
I have to reject the call after some ideal time so that I can show errors on my dashboard with project load.

```
angularLoad.loadScript(script)
    .then(function () {
        $scope.err = false;
    })
    .catch(function () {
        $scope.err = true;
    });
```

One solution is - apply timeout. Any other solutions?

Comment: Your code seems enough. Why do you want to set a timeOut?

Comment: No this angular script showing pending for some times on network tab. and rest other resource loads in seconds.
so my other details loads correctly on my dashboard and this err block is taking time to show because of the loading delay.
I wanted to show all details on same time

Comment: So you want to reject the promise after waiting for XX seconds?

Comment: Yes , I  want to reject the promise after waiting for XX seconds :)

Comment: Does [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994871/setting-a-timeout-handler-on-a-promise-in-angularjs) help you?

Comment: @Mistalis It make sense but still i need to reject my angular loadscript! after XX second timeout

Comment: read about [$q.race](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q#qrace