# Ui Router seems to never transition if promises are not resolved in resolve list w/ Selenium

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am assuming this is expected behavior, but I would think there has to be a way to handle this cleaner. I had the following code in my state declaration....

```
resolve:
    user: (AuthenticationService) ->
        return AuthenticationService.setup
```

This was fine until a bug in the code kept setup from never resolving. Even then it would work fine in a normal chrome browser. However, when I tried running tests using Selenium and Web Driver, it would freeze on a grey screen. When I debugged I found this line was waiting for the resolve of the promise that never resolved. So in this portion of angular ui

```
 dst.resolve = $resolve.resolve(state.resolve, locals, dst.resolve, state);
 var promises = [dst.resolve.then(function (globals) {
    dst.globals = globals;
 })];
```

The dst.resolve doesn't get called. The other problem is that we never see an error anywhere because the reject is just logged and it moves on (IE the bug was we were not rejecting after logging).

Is there a way to make sure the promises eventually timeout? I know this should probably just be an issue, however, it is relatively hard to make a plunker and I wanted to "talk it out" first.

Comment: In fact when I fix the bug it STILL doesn't work and instead logs silently `there was a problem angular-ui-router.js:3432`

Comment: You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994871/setting-a-timeout-handler-on-a-promise-in-angularjs) to find how to set a timeout on a promise

Comment: Thanks for that, I think it is still an issue though because even when I reject it bombs out